# Print XML return from CURL request

Tags: php, xml, curl

I am using a web API especially built for my client. It currently is being used, but I have no access to the code that already exists, so I have to rewrite the cURL request.

The responise is XML, but I have trouble reading it. This is my code:

```
$url = "http://www.url.com/";
$input_xml = "<test>data</test>";

//setting the curl parameters.
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "xmlRequest=" . $input_xml);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 300);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($data);
$oXML = new SimpleXMLElement($data);

foreach($oXML->entry as $oEntry){
    echo $oEntry->title . "\n";
}
```

When doing the `var_dump($data)` I receive this output: `string(45) "003 OK "`. Only seeing 6 characters, when the var_dump tells me there should be 45.

The `$oXML` code gives me the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in /home/mypath/file.php:31 Stack trace: #0 /home/mypath/file.php(31): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('<studio>003</st...') #1 {main} thrown in /home/mypath/file.php on line 31
```

When looking at this part of the error: `__construct('<studio>003</st...')` it seems that there actually is XML in the response. `<studio>003</studio>` is the beginning of the expected output the API should give.

How can I get the raw output from the cURL request?

Comment: First try to load the `xml` string with `simplexml_load_string` function then use `SimpleXMLElement` class

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue. The API returned only this: `<studio>003</studio><ip_check>OK</ipcheck>`, and you can't load this with `simplexml_load_string`. I had to add a node around it, so I basically did this:

```
$data = '<data>'.$data.'</data>';
```